# What to pay a model without experience

Tags: models

I'm in charge of finding, booking and shooting with models for a new clothing company. To fit the budget I've decided to only use regular people and not professional models since they tend to be less aware of the industry and therefor don't have any previous experience with the payment received. It is also what has been requested from the company since that is the aesthetic and vibe they are going for.

Since regular people who are offered to model often jump on to the opportunity just for the fun of it and are not really expecting anything, **how much should they get paid per hour for a studio session?**

I'm located in Stockholm, Sweden and the pictures will be used for commercial purposes.

Comment: Without at least giving us some idea of location, this is unanswerable. What you pay somebody in India is going to be very different to what you pay someone in Norway.

Comment: Are you shooting the sessions just for the fun of it? Or at a rate well below the prevailing one for a photographer in your locale?

Comment: What's the legal minimum wage in your area? You might use that as a starting point and then offer a bit over that

Comment: You run a huge risk of having your shots look like they were shot with everyday people as well, as in, people who aren't necessarily comfortable in front of the camera. Strikes me as a pretty big risk for a commercial job.

Comment: A very bad choice of cost to cut, IMO.  Decent experienced models make shooting and getting good shots easier (or possible might be a better word).  A clothing company not using pro models (most of whom earn not very much) and pro makeup artists does not bode well for the result.  My view, however, is that if the people you shoot are being used in commercial marketing material, then expect to pay commercial rates.

Answer (score 4):

> They tend to be less aware of the industry and therefore don't have any previous experience with the payment received.

I feel the way this question is been asked as unethical if you are simply trying to exploit lack of knowledge. (I hope is not the case) :o)

Find a local agency, probably not for models, but for host or aid personnel (the ones that show products on stores) They tend to be non-professional models, but somehow related to the industry.

Set up some fee accordingly and state that as such. If they agree, fine.

See if there are some guidance on your country regarding some labor union.

Also, regarding the image or voice of a person, there could be some royalty fees that need to be adressed, how long the campaign will be, the amount of distribution, the extension, the channel used, etc.

But find an expert legal advice, not just a random comment on a forum.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on local regulations, you may be able to get people to model in exchange for allowing them to utilize photos taken as part of their portfolio.  If they have no professional training or experience, it is effectively an internship for them.  The value they get out of it is in the experience and the resume/portfolio building.

It isn't exactly the same, but I've worked on low budget streaming TV shows where the vast majority of extras and even portions of the crew are unpaid and doing the work purely for the experience.

Note that this doesn't mean that the work is without cost though.  There are several real sources of cost still associated with "free" talent.

First, you need to make the environment welcoming for them.  We often provide food and snacks for our extras.  The environment is pretty laid back, but still professional enough for them to understand what they are getting in to and get their feet wet.  It is supposed to be educational for them, since they are effectively interning.

Second, the process takes longer.  You are working with people who lack experience, which means you have to provide training.  You need skilled crew members (who you do have to pay to attract) who are able to work with inexperienced models and it is more time consuming to both provide the necessary training and get the work done.

Third, and this may be a non-issue depending on your constraints, you need to offer them something that they can use for enhancing their career.  For models, it likely means giving them rights to use some of the imagery in their portfolio or possibly even doing a few extra shots just for them.  Offering each aspiring model a free professional head shot might be a good draw for example.

Ultimately, you get what you pay for and not all payments are cash.  There are lots of ways to get work done cheaply if you are willing to exchange time, but that can also bring costs up in other ways.  Ultimately, just try your best to figure out a way to make it a situation where everyone wins and that is legal in your jurisdiction and you should be able to do well.